# Two Form Post Actions - Pass data to another page AND email the data

Tags: php, forms, post

I am currently working on a form that needs two post actions with one submit button. I am not extremely versed in PHP, only know enough to make my way around current tasks, until now.

Here is the code for the page the form is on:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    if (empty($_POST['first']) || 
    empty($_POST['last']) || 
    empty($_POST['email']) ||
    empty($_POST['location'])) {
        $errors = 1;
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors = 2;
    } else {
        $to = "emailgoeshere@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Blah blah blah";
        $message .= "Name: ".$_POST['first']." ".$_POST['last']."\n";
        $message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
        $message .= "Cell Phone: ".$_POST['cell']."\n";
        $message .= "Location: ".$_POST['location']."\n";
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        header('Location: freepass.php');
        exit;
    }
}

if ($errors == 1) {
    $errors = "Please fill out all fields";
} elseif ($errors == 2) {
        $errors = "Please enter a valid email";
}

?>
```

This is the form action:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

This is the code on the page that the data will pass to:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $_POST["first"]; ?> <?php echo $_POST["last"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_POST["cell"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very quick solution but it should do the trick.

```
if ($_POST) {
    $errors = null;
    $error_message = "<ul>";

    if (empty($_POST['first']) || 
        empty($_POST['last']) || 
        empty($_POST['email']) || 
        empty($_POST['location'])) {
        $errors = 1;
    } 

    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors = 2;
    }

    if($errors == null) {
        $to = "grimegriever@gmail.com";
        $subject = "City Fitness 7-Day Pass Applicant";
        $message .= "Name: ".$_POST['first']." ".$_POST['last']."\n";
        $message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
        $message .= "Cell Phone: ".$_POST['cell']."\n";
        $message .= "Location: ".$_POST['location']."\n";
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $headers = "From:" . $from;

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header('Location: freepass.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        if ($errors == 1) {
            $error_message .= "<li>Please fill out all fields</li>";
        }

        if ($errors == 2) {
            $error_message .= "<li>Please enter a valid email</li>";
        }

        $error_message .= "</ul>";
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are much more efficient solutions, but this will work.